# How to fix Coroutine Timeout in Unit Test

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Use case class that get Data from Repository:

```
class GetAllGamesUseCase(
    private val repository: GameRepository
) {
    operator fun invoke():Flow<Resource<List<Game>>>{
        return repository.getAllGames()
    }
}
```

I have written a Test for that:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class GetAllGamesUseCaseTest{
    @get:Rule
    val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()


    private lateinit var game:Game
    private lateinit var repository: FakeGameRepository
    private lateinit var connectivityObserver: FakeNetworkConnectivityObserver


    @Before
    fun setup(){
        connectivityObserver = FakeNetworkConnectivityObserver()
        repository = FakeGameRepository(connectivityObserver)
        val games = mutableListOf<Game>()
        for(i in 0..10){
            game = Game(
                developer = "developer $i",
                freeToGameProfileUrl = "freeUrl $i",
                gameUrl = "gameUrl $i",
                genre = "genre $i",
                id = i,
                platform = "plat $i",
                publisher = "publish $i",
                releaseDate = "release $i",
                shortDescription = "short $i",
                thumbnail = "thumb $i",
                title = "title $i"
            )
            games.add(game)
        }
        repository.insertGame(games)

    }


    @Test
    fun `Get all games`() = runTest {
            connectivityObserver.setStatus(Status.Available)

            val result = repository.getAllGames()

            result.collect{

                assertThat(it.data).contains(game)
            }

    }
}
```

That Test was working fine with this Fake Repository function:

```
override fun getAllGames(): Flow<Resource<List<Game>>> {

    return flow {

                    emit(Resource.Success(games))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with this Fake Repository I didn't check Internet connection Status so I changed Fake Repository to this:

```
override fun getAllGames(): Flow<Resource<List<Game>>> {

    return flow {
        connectivityObserver.observe().collect{status ->
            when(status){
                Status.Available ->{
                    emit(Resource.Success(games))
                }
                else ->{
                    games = emptyList<Game>().toMutableList()
                    emit(Resource.Error("No Internet Connection"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the FakeNetworkConnectivityObserver:

```
class FakeNetworkConnectivityObserver:ConnectivityObserver{
    private val statusFlow = MutableStateFlow(Status.Unavailable)

    fun setStatus(status: Status){
        statusFlow.value = status
    }
    override fun observe(): Flow<Status> {
        return statusFlow
    }

    }
```

After that change my Usecase Test has this Error:

```
After waiting for 10s, the test coroutine is not completing
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 10s, the test coroutine is not completing
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$2$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt:349)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$2$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt:333)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.InvokeOnCancelling.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1430)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1474)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:798)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:758)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:674)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelCoroutine(JobSupport.kt:661)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCoroutine.run(Timeout.kt:159)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase$DelayedRunnableTask.run(EventLoop.common.kt:501)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor.run(DefaultExecutor.kt:108)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

How can I fix this Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That Test was working fine with this Fake Repository function:

```kotlin
flow {
    emit(Resource.Success(games))
}
```

This is a flow that `emit`s one single value, then completes. Equivalent to [`flowOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow-of.html)`(Resource.Success(games))`.

---

```kotlin
statusFlow.collect { status ->
    when (status){
        Status.Available -> {
            emit(Resource.Success(games))
        }
        else -> {
            games = emptyList<Game>().toMutableList()
            emit(Resource.Error("No Internet Connection"))
        }
    }
}
```

This is a flow that `emit`s one value per value in `statusFlow`.

Since the state flow last forever, so does this flow.

---

The following flow checks the current state, and emits one single element.

```kotlin
flow {
    emit(when (connectivityObserver.observe().fist()) {
        ...
    })
}
```

Comment: There is no value for ConnectivityObserver.observe(). Can you modify my Repository?

Comment: Right, because the return type of `observe()` is up-casted `Flow<Status>`. I changed my code to [`.first()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/first.html).